# How to connect MySQL workbench with MAMP PRO?

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

What is the fix to connect the [MySQL Workbench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench) tool with the [MAMP PRO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) MySQL database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to get http://www.sequelpro.com/ working by pointing it to the socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 85):

Change the connection type from `TCP/IP` to `Local`, then point it to the socket:

`/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Your username and pw will most likely be root / root

Comment: This was precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: Wonder why the other answer was selected :)

Comment: After I set the above parameters, I received: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)"

Answer (score 23):

As [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256144/407456) said you can use the Local option and point it to the socket:

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Or you can generate a symbolic link to your mysql socket (from your terminal):

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/
```

Doing it this way **the changes will be permanent** and you will be able to connect to mysql using the `mysqlcli` or any other external tool.

Answer (score 9):

After looking around for quite some time, Mike's answer worked great.

However, I also discovered that going into MySQL tab and checking `Allow network access to MySQL` and choosing the `only from this Mac` radio button I was able to connect using the previously saved connection in MySQL Workbench that I had been using with standard MAMP before upgrading to MAMP Pro.

[image: MAMP Pro MySQL settings for allowing local network access]

So for those of you who are moving from MAMP to MAMP Pro and already have your connections setup in MySQL Workbench, this option is quicker than setting up a new connection using a unix socket.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it by unchecking the "Allow local access only" checkbox in the Server->MySQL Tab

Comment: Sometimes things are very simple

Answer (score 2):

[image: CONNECTION TO DB with MAMP]

Connection to DB with MAMP.
You must use local connection

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the ports. As well explained [here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/01/19/fix-mamp-mysql-workbench-failed-connect-mysql/), the default mysql port in MAMP is 8889, and not 3306, although in MAMP localhost website says that it`s running in 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only able to connect if I use the socket `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` AND set "Run Apache/MySQL as user `www/mysql`" in the gerneral tab.

Answer (score 0):

If, after following [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256144/407456) answer you receive:

```
Operation failed: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start is invalid
```

Follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685584). For me, I had to replace */usr/local/mysql* with */Application/MAMP/Library* in the fields:

- Start MySQL:
- Stop MySQL:
- Check MySQL Status:

Answer (score 0):

When I have to make this connection, I set my TCP/IP connection to socket and UN/pw both to root as Mike suggests above. However workbench was still telling me that it was looking for a cnf file at this location (/etc/my.cnf).

I created a symlink from my MAMP cnf file to the location that Workbench was looking for it.
(sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/support-files/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf)

setup finalized without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure MySQL is set to "on" in addition to Apache or nginx.  The `Servers` button may not toggle all of them.

In my case, only Apache was running :)

Answer (score 0):

MAMP server typically uses 8889 port instead of 3306. You can check it in MAMP/SQL section.[image]