# MySQL Workbench : Server Administration Configuration - HOW TO

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am getting an error upon trying to Create New Server Instance Profile [(click this to see the image)](http://bit.ly/JpgrKS) :

Operation failed: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start is invalid

I am not sure where the setting panel is for the workbench to fix the start and stop commands, and the location of '/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server'. I am using Zend Server CE and I have no directory called '/usr/local/mysql', instead mysql.server is situated in '/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin' but how do I tell Workbench to look for it in the appropriate place.

The start and stop commands are :

sudo /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.server

Again how do I fix this for workbench.

Answer (score 9):

You can find MySQL setting in your Mac system settings page. Go there, you can start or stop mysql server. It works for me with OSX 10.11.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that MySQL Workbench is using a command to start/stop the server that doesn't work for your setting. You should manually correct it.

In the main WB screen, go to **Manage Server Instances** (near the lower right corner) and select the server instance you are using in the list control to the left. Then go to the **System Profile** tab and change your commands accordingly.

Comment: in WB 6.3, in the main WB screen click on the Wrench icon in the top left corner to go to Manage Server Instances.

Answer (score 3):

On MacOS Big Sur it would be like that:
Go to Server -> Management Access Settings -> System Profile tab, and put in MySQL Management boxes below commands:

```
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Remember to check option: Elevate privileges to execute start/stop command and write configuration data.

My installation was from .dmg file. Funny thing, every time I was trying to stop or start server, had to check that box to elevate privileges before, it was unchecking by itself.

Comment: This is the answer. The others mysteriously restate the question. Workbench 8.0.22 I was able to do; `Database -> Manage Connections -> Chose a local instance -> System Profile` and under `MySQL Management` add the start/stop scripts.